# How to resolve ModelBindingExecutionContext is a type but used like a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-binding

I'm attempting to implement Model Binding but I'm receiving an error: ModelBindingExecutionContext is a type but used like a variable. Here is my code:
(Should specify this is for ASP.NET Web Form Application not MVC)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.ModelBinding;

    protected ActivityBO GetActivity()
    {
        ActivityBO activity = new ActivityBO();            
        //IValueProvider provider = new FormValueProvider(ModelBindingExecutionContext);
        if (TryUpdateModel(activity, new FormValueProvider(ModelBindingExecutionContext)))
        {
            return activity;
        }
        else
        {
            //Error code will go here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the class you are inheriting from? Are you sure you want to invoke a Business Object from a model binder?

Comment: @Ramesh I will post the object but yes this object is a just a model

Comment: You can get the value provider from `bindingContext.ValueProvider` instead of relying on creating a new instance of `FormValueProvider` ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Nobody never reads exception messages. _ModelBindingExecutionContext is a type but used like a variable_ means that your `ModelBindingExecutionContext` is a `type`, but you try to pass it to `FormValueProvider` constructor like it is a `variable`. You can't pass `type`s like it is a `variable`.

Comment: @vasily.sib thanks for the response, but I'm attempting to test this method and part of the code I'm using is identical to sample code found on the web and in Apress Pro Asp.net 4.5. Can you recommend a fix or the proper way to implement this method

Comment: @jrobinson6274, this is not a question of _proper way_ of implementation, you have a very general C# language misuse. It's like writing `var foo = "2²"` and expecting, that now `foo == 4`. We need more code to understand what is wrong. What is a class which have this `GetActivity` method? What is his super-class (parent)?

Comment: I found the problem, turns out the code was fine. The problem is I was attempting to use System.Web.ModelBinding on a User Control which doesn't inherit from System.Web.UI.Page